Where can I find native German speakers to practice with for free?
I find it easier to learn German when I practice speaking or conversing. Could someone tell me where I can find native German speakers to practice with for free?

Obvious answer: in Germany, Austria and parts of Switzerland and Belgium. But that's not what you are looking for? Maybe you can include more details on what (and where) you are thinking of

I'm not sure this is on-topic for the site since it's more about language learning than the German language. If you do have questions about German there are many native German speakers here you can ask, but the site is not meant for practicing German.

@planetmaker: also:parts of Italy, Tinder, Parship, Elitepartners, ... :)

Moved this answer to the top level

www.mylanguageexchange.com
It's free, but I recommend paying the $6 to get the "gold" membership for at least a month, which makes it easier to find people.

You might be having a hard time finding people that will simply spend their free time talking to you in German (those guys already know the language...).
Your chances might be a lot better if you can offer something in exchange (like offering the same thing, just in your native language, whatever that might be). So, the problem boils down to finding German ex-pats in your country.

This Meetup group is great for practicing. They meet every week:
Portland German Conversation
Portland, OR, USA
1,403 members · Public group
Organized by Peter Klein

I would look for a local German "society" where you live. I'm in a town on East Coast of USA, and we have a German society here. We have occasional social meetings for chatting/conversation; for example tomorrow we're meeting at a local pub to view Germany play against Hungary in the Euro championship series.  Where are you located?
